# How to copy the elements of array of unequal length to another?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a simple problem i am trying to solve as shown below:

```
import random
n=399
x=np.random.randn(n,n)
m=400
y=np.zeros((m,m))
```

How can i copy the elements from x to y, taking the specified position?
Any help will be much appreciated

Note, the value of m and n can change depend on the number of nodes in the graph

Comment: Do you want the x values to start at [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0] or [0, 0]?

Comment: @andrew i want the elements of x to be copied to y, taking the same position as in x

Comment: `y[slice(0, n), slice(0, n)] = x` should do it

Comment: Thank you @Andrew,  good answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reshape` function in combination with `ravel`. The idea is to reshape the `x` and `y` to linear `1D` arrays, copy the desired values and transform them back to original dimensions.

```
x = x.ravel()
y = y.ravel()

y[0: len(x)] = x
x = x.reshape(n, n)
y = y.reshape(m, m)
```

If I'm using `n = 2` and `m = 3`, this is how it looks the result.

*Output*

```
> x
array([[ 0.91967292, -0.72831929],
   [ 0.01405106,  0.48574124]])

> y
array([[ 0.91967292, -0.72831929,  0.01405106],
   [ 0.48574124,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

If you want to use a starting `position` then we just need to change it to:

```
x = x.ravel()
y = y.ravel()

position = 2

if len(x) + position < len(y):
  y[position: len(x) + position] = x
else:
  y[position: len(y)] = x[0: len(y) - position]

x = x.reshape(n, n)
y = y.reshape(m, m)
```

*Output*

```
> x
array([[ 0.27871393,  0.07950119],
   [ 0.20680902, -0.50625609]])

> y
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.27871393],
   [ 0.07950119,  0.20680902, -0.50625609],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you mean. If you want the elements of the smaller array to be placed into the larger array in the same shape and arrangement, you could just assign to a slice of the array:

```
>>> a = np.zeros((5, 5))
>>> b = np.ones((2, 3))
>>> bx, by = b.shape
>>> a[1:1+bx, 2:2+by] = b
>>> a
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: Thank you @tobias_k for the good answer, but still i need some elaboration. Assume the first adjacency matrix(small matrix) is having nodes 1,2,,4 and second matrix(large matrix)-filled with zeros is having node 1,2,3,4. I want all entry of each node in first matrix to be filled in the second matrix, notably here the entries of node 3 should all be zeros, because it is not having any values(not there) in the first matrix.